# ER-Diagram : How to manage sessions ? (parallel drupal <-> symfony2)

Tags: drupal, session, session-variables, symfony, erd

I am building my app and have been annoyed concerning sessions storage. I am a newbie about sessions. I am working with Symfony2 and MySQL, and as Symfony is storage-agnostic, I am searching into the **[Drupal 7 diagram](http://upsitesweb.com/sites/upsites.co/files/drupal7_model_0.png)** to find a good model.

So I wondered a couple of things :

- How to manage sessions in an Entity-Relationship diagram ?
- In drupal 7 diagram, what do sessions->fields mean ?

  - Sessions -> uid (int(10)) -> OK
  - Sessions -> sid (varchar(128)) ?
  - Sessions -> ssid (varchar(128)) ?
  - Sessions -> hostname (varchar(128)) -> OK
  - Sessions -> timestamp (int(11)) -> guessing date of connection
  - Sessions -> cache (int(11)) -> Why only an integer ?
  - Sessions -> session (longblob) -> What do you put inside ?

As I imagined my own diagram, I had 2 tables :

- Session that stored the sessionId, cookie and establishing date
- User_Session, association between Sessions and Users, which stores IP address and DateInit.

Why not storing one session by Cookie and storing also each time the user connects ?
If someone could help me understand and help me find the true entity-relationship model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description of the session table from Drupal 7 is given in its [`system_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.install/function/system_schema/7) function:

```
  $schema['sessions'] = array(
    'description' => "Drupal's session handlers read and write into the sessions table. Each record represents a user session, either anonymous or authenticated.", 
    'fields' => array(
      'uid' => array(
        'description' => 'The {users}.uid corresponding to a session, or 0 for anonymous user.', 
        'type' => 'int', 
        'unsigned' => TRUE, 
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ), 
      'sid' => array(
        'description' => "A session ID. The value is generated by Drupal's session handlers.", 
        'type' => 'varchar', 
        'length' => 128, 
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ), 
      'ssid' => array(
        'description' => "Secure session ID. The value is generated by Drupal's session handlers.", 
        'type' => 'varchar', 
        'length' => 128, 
        'not null' => TRUE, 
        'default' => '',
      ), 
      'hostname' => array(
        'description' => 'The IP address that last used this session ID (sid).', 
        'type' => 'varchar', 
        'length' => 128, 
        'not null' => TRUE, 
        'default' => '',
      ), 
      'timestamp' => array(
        'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when this session last requested a page. Old records are purged by PHP automatically.', 
        'type' => 'int', 
        'not null' => TRUE, 
        'default' => 0,
      ), 
      'cache' => array(
        'description' => "The time of this user's last post. This is used when the site has specified a minimum_cache_lifetime. See cache_get().", 
        'type' => 'int', 
        'not null' => TRUE, 
        'default' => 0,
      ), 
      'session' => array(
        'description' => 'The serialized contents of $_SESSION, an array of name/value pairs that persists across page requests by this session ID. Drupal loads $_SESSION from here at the start of each request and saves it at the end.', 
        'type' => 'blob', 
        'not null' => FALSE, 
        'size' => 'big',
      ),
    ), 
    'primary key' => array(
      'sid',
      'ssid',
    ), 
    'indexes' => array(
      'timestamp' => array('timestamp'), 
      'uid' => array('uid'), 
      'ssid' => array('ssid'),
    ), 
    'foreign keys' => array(
      'session_user' => array(
        'table' => 'users', 
        'columns' => array('uid' => 'uid'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

But this is not an E-R model. Also, it heavily depends on Drupal own session handling function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which gives enlightenment.

Now I wonder : "The Unix timestamp when this session last requested a page. Old records are purged by PHP automatically." -> Isn't this no good for stats ?

I am also surprised that the primary key is SID AND SSID.

Comment: @Le Barde - the SID and SSID are unique so it's no surprise that they're the primary keys. "The Unix timestamp when this session last requested a page. Old records are purged by PHP automatically." This works the same on normal session storage, i.e. when a session is initialised, a file is created in a directory on the file system (usually under the /tmp/ directory), when the session is no longer valid, it is removed automatically. The database approach is doing exactly the same thing. If you want to do statistics, then you need to log to another table.